# iTextSharp file manipulation and display to FileStreamResults

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying top open a PDF file using iTextSharp, add a dataset to the file to prepopulate data, then save it to a stream so that I can display it to the users.  I don't want to save it locally to a file. I keep getting the error "Cannot access a closed Stream." I can't figure out which stream is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
public FileStreamResult PushDataIntoPDFStream(string filename)
{     
     var reader = new PdfReader(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(path), filename));
     var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
          <form1>  
             <firstName>test</firstName>
             <lastName>user</lastName>
             <driveCar>0</driveCar>
             <gender>1</gender>
             <birthdate>2011-08-12</birthdate>
             <numPets>4</numPets>
          </form1>";

     using (var outstream = new MemoryStream())
     { 
          using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outstream))
          {
               var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
               using (var ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
               {
                    stamper.AcroFields.Xfa.FillXfaForm(ms);
               }
          }

          return new FileStreamResult(outstream, "application/pdf")
          {
                FileDownloadName = "file.pdf";
          };
     }      
  }
```

Comment: Have you tried taking the `return` outside of the `using`?

Comment: @Nate yes.  I can get it working if I save it to a file and then show it but I am trying to show it without saving it first and so far no combination has worked.  I have a bad feeling that I am going to have to save temp files.

Answer (score 5):

The `PdfStamper` has a `.CloseStream` property on its internal output stream; try setting it to false:

```
using (var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, outstream))
{
    stamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
```

Comment: Spot on. This worked for me. If re-using the stream, however, don't forget to call outstream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin).